# Geologica data UDM(unusable data mask) have 8 bits per pixel

Tags: raster, rasterio, cloud-cover, geoplanet

**UNUSABLE DATA MASK FILE(UDM)**

The unusable data mask file provides information on areas of unusable data within an image (e.g. cloud and 
non-imaged areas).
The pixel size after orthorectification will be 50 m for RapidEye, Each bit in the 8-bit pixel identifies whether the corresponding part of 
the product contains useful imagery:

- Bit 0: Identifies whether the area contains blackfill.
- Bit 1: Identifies whether the area is cloud covered.
- Bit 2: Identifies whether the area contains missing (lost during downlink)or suspect (contains down- link errors)

and so all bits have their responsibilities.
**I want to read the Bit 1 of a pixel in UDM file.**